# Ubuntu 13.10 and DisplayLink adapter

Tags: 13.10, displaylink

I'm using 13.10, and have upgraded my kernel to `3.14rc5` and blacklisted `udlfb`.  I boot up, plug in the DisplayLink adapter, and everything appears to be peachy at first blush:

```
> lsusb
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17e9:0360 DisplayLink
```

So far so good.  Taking a gander at `xrandr`, I can see the HDMI and DVI outputs. If I look in the display settings (or `arandr`), I can see both outputs.  When I check the output from `dmesg`, I see the DisplayLink adapter get picked up, but it never gets attached to a device.  This feels very fishy, but I'm still fairly new at this and hitting a wall.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get some signs of life on the setup I had in my question and after playing with the resolutions (setting to a lower resolution seemed to help).  I'm not sure the resolutions are mapped properly, but at least I'm getting an image.

Answer (score 0):

I followed almost the same exact steps. Here's some things that might help that I've done/realized, taken from [an ubuntu forums discussion of this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190074)

1. It doesn't work for me unless I have the usb monitor plugged in when I start up.
2. Instead of blacklisting udlfb, blacklist udl, as explained in that forum. To do this, add `blacklist udl` to a new file called `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf`. Then comment out the `blacklist udlfb` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf`.
3. To finish it out, I just went to `system settings -> display`, activated the USB monitor, and it came on. I had booted with the displaylink adapter plugged in.

Currently I'm running two external monitors on a MacBook Pro 9,1. It's a little sluggish at times, and my cursor is blinking a lot when I use the built-in monitor along with the two external. Setting the system to not sleep on closing the lid and closing the lid gets rid of the blinking and sluggishness.

Comment: Funnily enough, that was the article I had originally based most of my tinkering off of.  I did eventually get it to "work."  See my answer.